# Search filter in a custom list view

Tags: android, searchview, custom-adapter

I am trying to add a search filter in a custom list view. several time i have try but still have problem. Here search filter visually show iin action bar but doesn't work. Anyone can fix this please.....

Mainactivity.java

```
public class Sulphur extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;
private  String[] productName;
private  String[] genericName;
private   String[] companyName;
private   String[] apNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sulphur);
    listView= findViewById(R.id.lv_Sulphur);
    this.setTitle("Sulphur");
    productName =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sulphur);
    genericName =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sulphur_Generic);
    companyName= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sulphur_Company);
    apNumber=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sulphur_AP);

    CustomAdapter adapter= new CustomAdapter(this, productName,genericName,companyName,apNumber);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.layout_menu, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchMenuID);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

            String text= s;

            CustomAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            return true;
        }
    });


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

Custom Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

String[] productName;
String[] genericName;
String[] companyName;
String[] apNumber;
Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;


CustomAdapter(Context context, String[]productName, String[]genericName,String[] companyName,String[] apNumber ){

    this.context=context;
    this.productName=productName;
    this.genericName=genericName;
    this.companyName=companyName;
    this.apNumber=apNumber;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return productName.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if(view==null){
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_view,viewGroup,false);
    }

    TextView textView=view.findViewById(R.id.Product_textviewID);
    TextView textView2=view.findViewById(R.id.Generic_texviewtID);
    TextView textView3=view.findViewById(R.id.Company_texviewtID);
    TextView textView4=view.findViewById(R.id.APNumber_texviewtID);

    textView.setText(productName[i]);
    textView3.setText(companyName[i]);
    textView4.setText(apNumber[i]);
    textView2.setText(genericName[i]);

    return view;
}
public static android.widget.Filter getFilter(){
    return new android.widget.Filter(){

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

        }
    };
}

}
```

Comment: you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<YourItemDataModel> { ...` and override its `onBind()` and `matches()` methods - some sample code is [here](http://pastebin.com/07mBMT0t)

Comment: What can i do with my code..please explain details..i will be pleased to you..

Comment: when can i get this code sir...??

Comment: sir sorry for silly question.  am new in android development..  am i replace my code with your code...?

Comment: please sir explain what should i do....

Comment: this code doesn't work sir

Comment: there have any other way?? please see my code and tell me what i exact need to do. please sir

Comment: all you need to do is to extend `MatchableArrayAdapter` - dont you know how to extend some class in java?

Comment: No i don't know...